# Как в python задать глобальную переменную в функции не используя global

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, global-variables

Я хочу задать глобальную переменную в функции. Это легко можно сделать с помощью `global`, но везде пишут, что из-за этого может возникнуть много проблем и вообще во многих случаях лучше не использовать `global`, считая каждый его вызов ошибкой в коде.

Вот условный пример моего кода:

```
a = ''

def func():
    a = input()
    if not a:
        print('a is empty')
    else:
        print('a is not empty')

func()
```

Этот код условно должен проверять **`a`** - это пустая переменная или нет.

Как мне сделать, чтобы пустая строка **`a`** заменилась на то, что введет пользователь и запомнилась глобально?

Answer (score 3):

Глобальные переменные плохи не от того, что они задаются описателем `global`. Они плохи потому, что неявное описание переменных усложняет логику программ, ее читаемость, отлаживаемость и предсказуемость результатов.  Вы их или используете  (и неважно как ) или нет.  А если используете - то точно понимая все риски и точно понимая, зачем вы на них идете. И ответив (хотя-бы себе) на вопрос -  а без них можно?

А если делать все "как положено" -  то просто передаете переменную в функцию явно, а в функции выполняете свои проверки и модификации. Только и всего -  просто и понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
def func(a):
#    a = input()
    if not a:
        print('\na is empty')
        a = f'a is empty --> `{a}`'
    else:
        print('\na is not empty')
        a = f'a is not empty --> `{a}`'
    return a

a = ''        
a = func(a)
print(f'1. a = {a}')

a = 'Hello'        
a = func(a)
print(f'2. a = {a}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше передать функции эту переменную, провести с ней какие-то действия, и вернуть результат функции через 'return', и переписать переменную.

Comment: Чем это отличается от уже данного ответа?

Comment: Тем что он дан раньше

Comment: Ой, сорри. Не заметил из очереди.

Comment: Ничего страшного)

Answer (score 0):

Вынеси переменную за блок функций

```
a = 1
b = 2
def ab():
    print(a + b)
```

вывод: 3

Comment: Ну это на самом деле и есть глобальные переменные. Просто пока вы их не модифицируете в функции, питон не требует использовать в ней ключевое слово `global`

Answer (score 0):

Помимо уже написанного про функции и передачу параметром, есть случаи, когда вам нужно, например, хранить некие параметры, к которым должен быть доступ сразу у многих ваших функций или классов. В этом случае, конечно, неудобно передавать эти параметры в явном виде в каждую функцию.

Вот в этом случае можно завести, например, специальный класс, который хранит эти параметры, а все ваши функции берут параметры из полей этого класса. А сам этот класс может загружать параметры из файла, например. Класс этот можно вынести в отдельный файл и импортировать этот файл когда нужны эти параметры.

Хотя по сути класс - это тоже в общем-то глобальная переменная, но класс - это лучше, чем переменная, переменные обычно называют абы как, а у класса скорее всего будет выделенное "говорящее" название и в одном классе будет собрано много параметров, а не так, что много глобальных переменных непонятно откуда взявшихся, ищи потом, откуда они, как и чего.

Ещё в случае, если вам нужно менять какие-то переменные в нескольких функциях, удобно вынести эти переменные в какой-то класс опять же, а функции сделать методами этого класса. Тогда эти функции-методы будут иметь прямой доступ к этим переменным-полям, при этом они не будут засорять этими переменными глобальное пространство имён и мешать другим функциям/классам. Чем и хороша собственно *инкапсуляция* - один из трёх принципов, на которых стоит ООП.

Answer (score 0):

Как самый простой и самый понятный вариант

```
def func():
    a = input()
    if not a:
        print('a is empty')
        return ''

    else:
        print('a is not empty')
        return a

a = func()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]